# VB Parse a text file, match column 1 to a variable, pass column 2 to another variable

Tags: vb.net

I've written a script that will take a table out of a program, and export it to the local drive in a *comma delimited* text file. What I need is a script to read the text file. The user will input a string in a text box from Public Class Form 1, then the string gets passed to another Sub in Public Class `SpaceMenuClass`. The handoff looks ok, but I can't figure out how to parse the text file (match column 1 with the string, and store column 2 from that line to pass back to the `SpacemenuClass`). I know this may seem ambiguous, but hopefully makes some sense. Thanks to anyone in advance.

**From Form1 Class**

```
Private Sub BtnPlano_Click_(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPlano.Click
    If TxtBoxPlano.Text <> "" Then
        SpaceCommands.SearchPlano(TxtBoxPlano.Text)
    Else MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Valid Planogram Name!")

    End If
    TxtBoxPlano.Clear()

End Sub
```

**From SpaceMenuClass:**

```
Public Sub SearchPlano(PlanoName As String)
    For Each Plano As Space.Planogram In SpacePlanning.ForPlanograms()
        SpacePlanning.SetActivePlanogram(Plano.Number - 1)
        'Go open the Searchplano table on the shared drive
        SpacePlanning.OpenTableChartView(AnalysisFileName:="\\SERVER1\JDA\Tables\SearchPlano.pst")
        'Export the table to a Tab Delimited Text file
        SpacePlanning.ExportTableData(ExportFileName:="C:\Temp\JDA\SearchPlano.txt", ExportMethod:=ExportMethod.CommaSeparated, UseCurrency:=False, UseQuotedStrings:=False, UseThousandsSeparator:=False)
        'Close the Table
        SpacePlanning.CloseTableChartView(AnalysisFileName:="\\SERVER1\JDA\Tables\SearchPlano.pst")
        ' Open the text file and parse it
        Dim str As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(New System.IO.FileStream("C:\Temp\JDA\SearchPlano.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
        Dim strline, arr(), Name, Nbr As String
        Try
 NextLine:
            strline = str.ReadLine
            arr = strline.Split(",")
            Name = arr(0)
            Nbr = arr(1)
            If Name = PlanoName Then
                SpacePlanning.SetActivePlanogram(Plano.Number = Nbr)
                GoTo Finish
            Else
                GoTo NextLine
            End If
        Catch
        End Try
    Next
Finish:
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Temp\JDA\SearchPlano.Txt")
End Sub
```

Comment: What goes wrong with what you have now?  What error or exception do you get?

Comment: Oh sorry, that info would help. I get a cmd popup that quickly disappears. It there a line I can add to make it stay on screen?

Comment: I'm not even sure from the code posted where the cmd popup would be coming from---it might be from one of the things you call in SpacePlanning.  It doesn't necessarily indicate that there's anything going wrong.  Are you getting an exception, or is there some other kind of output that isn't what you expect?

Comment: So to sum it up, The table is out of JDA Space Planning, it's what Category Advisors use to help draw shelves for retailers. The planogram files contain multiple planograms (or shelf drawings), which have a name and a number, among other metadata. I'm using Space Automation Pro, which is based on VB with JDA plugins using their language, which will talk to Space Planning. I'm expecting the program to ask the user to to input a planogram name, column 1 in the text file, then jump to the planogram's number in column 2. You can't jump to a planogram by its name, only number. It just stays on #1

Comment: I can see that it opens the table, I look in the C:\temp directory and see it exports the file properly, then closes the table. It doesn't seem to find a match on the planogram name vs what the user input. As a test I copied the name straight from the table it exports to make sure no syntax issues are present. I feel the issue lies From "Dim str" and down

Comment: You might find it more helpful if you change your `catch` to `catch ex as exception` and do something to observe (breakpoint) or log the exception.  Your current exception handler is an anti-pattern and may be preventing you from seeing the problem.

Comment: Same goes for labels `NextLine:` and `Finish:`. The flow of your program can be controlled with loops, which are much easier for a human to interpret and maintain. Think `Do ... Loop While Name = PlanoName` or something along those lines

Comment: Also, opening the files multiple times, when seemingly (I might be wrong) no changes are being made to the files between opening. Then not [disposing your resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bwa4xa9(v=vs.110).aspx) (at least the StreamReader, possibly the SpacePlanning object elsewhere).

Comment: Now that I've read it, that's probably your issue, that the file has remained open from one iteration to the next, and it's not disposed (closed). Wrap the StreamReader in a Using block. See the link in my last comment.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick help. I have to run for the day and will start first thing on making these adjustments in the morning. Really appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the file for reading, then try to delete it before closing it. This would raise an exception. To avoid this, wrap the StreamReader in a `Using` block. The `End Using` automatically disposes of the object (closes the file for you).

```
Public Sub SearchPlano(planoName As String)
    For Each plano As Space.Planogram In SpacePlanning.ForPlanograms()
        SpacePlanning.SetActivePlanogram(plano.Number - 1)
        'Go open the Searchplano table on the shared drive
        SpacePlanning.OpenTableChartView(AnalysisFileName:="\\SERVER1\JDA\Tables\SearchPlano.pst")
        'Export the table to a Tab Delimited Text file
        SpacePlanning.ExportTableData(
            ExportFileName:="C:\Temp\JDA\SearchPlano.txt", ExportMethod:=ExportMethod.CommaSeparated,
            UseCurrency:=False, UseQuotedStrings:=False, UseThousandsSeparator:=False)
        'Close the Table
        SpacePlanning.CloseTableChartView(AnalysisFileName:="\\SERVER1\JDA\Tables\SearchPlano.pst")
        ' Open the text file and parse it
        Using str = New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Temp\JDA\SearchPlano.txt")
            Dim arr(), name, nbr As String
            Do
                If str.EndOfStream Then
                    ' didn't find item!!!
                End If
                arr = str.ReadLine.Split(",")
                name = arr(0)
                nbr = arr(1)
            Loop Until name = planoName
            SpacePlanning.SetActivePlanogram(plano.Number = nbr)
        End Using
    Next
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Temp\JDA\SearchPlano.Txt")
End Sub
```

I also cleaned up your loop and added a check for `EndOfStream`, in case you couldn't find a match (this would have thrown an exception too).

Also, changed the StreamReader to just open the file. You had a nested FileStream object in there, which would have required another `Using` block, and is unnecessary.

Comment: Djv, I was actually just going down that path as you mentioned it yesterday. I placed the Spaceplanning commands above the For Each command and it's running through a ton faster! However, when I copy over your suggestion, it never matches name to planoname. I added a Messagebox.show(name) after the Loop Until statement, and found that for each iteration of the Do Loop, the name string always contains the same value, it's like it's not stepping down to the next line in the text file to match on the Planoname. Does that make sense? I'm going to attach the txt file as well.

Comment: This would be an example of the text file.  Name,Number
AAAAAAAA,46
BBBBBBBB,47
CCCCCCCC,21
DDDDDDDD,42
EEEEEEEE,41
FFFFFFFF,43
GGGGGGGG,45
HHHHHHHH,44
IIIIIIII,7

Comment: A colleague of mine and I figured it out. We needed to exit the For loop, because it was matching perfectly as it should have but would leave and iterate through the next planogram in the file. This was on me for not being able to articulate that. That being said, you were still able to get me 90% of the way there, thanks to you and everyone else who helped.

Comment: @KevinG Ok, great.